# Using the same position for dragged image and its element

Tags: javascript

When dragging an image, I want the dragged image and the element itself to have the same position to make it look fluid.

```js
var troll = document.getElementById('troll');
var x, y = 0;

troll.addEventListener('drag', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  var left = e.clientX - 40 + 'px';
  var top = e.clientY - 40 + 'px';
  if (x < e.clientX) {   
   e.target.style.left = left;
  }
  else {
   e.target.style.left = left--;
  }
  if (y < e.clientY) {
   e.target.style.top = top;
  }
  else {
   e.target.style.top = top--;
  }
  x = e.clientX - e.target.width;
  y = e.clientY - e.target.height;
}, false);
```

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="troll">
  <img src="http://images.mmorpg.com/features/7909/images/Troll.png" alt="Troll">
</div>
```

As you see, I have tried it with

```
var left = e.clientX - 40 + 'px';
var top = e.clientY - 40 + 'px';
```

which is better than nothing but it doesn't look perfect, because `40` is just a static number. I have also tried it with `e.clientX - e.target.width + 'px'` and `e.clientY - e.target.height + 'px'` but it doesn't work.

How can I use a dynamic number? Or if there is a better solution, please let me know.